# How to write subprocess results to a file?

Tags: python

I will like to capture the results of `subprocess.checkoutput` to a file, but not sure how to write that using file IO. Can anyone help?
Code :

```
test = subprocess.checkoutput('command to execute',shell=True)
fdesc= open('result.txt','w')
for line in test:
    fdesc.write((test.readlines)+'/')
```

I expect it to write to file, but see I am making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `readlines` with `check_output`. Also, the output is `bytes`. So you have to convert it to string first.

```
test = subprocess.check_output('command to run', shell=True)
fdesc= open('result.txt','w')
for line in test.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
    fdesc.write((line)+'/')
```